# Full text search in webform

Tags: views, webforms, search

I have created a form using webform and used in views to display filled entries. Now I want to make *full text search* which can search data from available data in webforms. I have tried to index webform field but there is no webform type in index type in search Api. Please help, how can I do this?

Comment: This link can answer your question better.
https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/neschi/2522034 Also the post have detailed information of implementation(http://www.neschi.com/blog/webform-selectable-filters/)